# How to build large single XML Document over multiple batches

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, xml

I would like to understand if it's possible to generate large XML files using [XmlNode and Document classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_Dom_Document_load) in Batch apex?

Ideally, I would like the Dom.Document class variable to be stateful. However, this is not possible. As an attempted workaround, I have serialised the document into a string. This works in execute anonymous however it does not work in batch (System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: dom.XmlNode).

I have tried creating the file synchronously and also using @Future however both failed with CPU timeout beyond a small number of records. That is why I would like to create the XML document in small chunks within Salesforce governor limits.

Note that the code below has been simplified for illustration purposes.

Thanks in advance

```
public with sharing class ExampleBatchJob  implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

Dom.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
Dom.XmlNode root = doc.createRootElement('AccountPerformanceSalesData', null, null);
String theDocAsString = doc.toXmlString();

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

    Dom.Document doc2 = new DOM.Document();
    doc2.load(theDocAsString);
    List<Account> accountList = scope;
    for (Account acc : accountList) {
        doc2.getRootElement().addChildElement('test', 'test', 'test');
    }
    theDocAsString = doc2.toXmlString();
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug(theDocAsString);
}
```

Comment: Please use **text** instead of an **image** for your code. This makes it easier for users that use screen readers and people trying to answer your question.

Comment: Sure thing. Apologies I didn't know but makes total sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize `doc` or `root`. Remove them from the class, and initialize `theDocAsString` in your `start(Database.BatchableContext context)` method.

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
  doc.createRootElement(...);
  theDocAsString = doc.toXmlString();
  return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @sfdcfox. You are the man, as always.